# Sharing UI validation between forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, events

I am trying to figure out how to seperate my business logic from my forms.  This is my first attempt at doing this, but I would like to figure out how to handle events from multiple forms within a class.  I have found myself routinely writing the same logic over and over in each form class and its time I figure out how to completly seperate out that logic in winforms so I can reuse the methods across all of my forms.

So basically I have this click event in form1:

```
    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPlanName.Text) OrElse _
            String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPlanNumber.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("All of the fields are not filled in!" + Environment.NewLine + _
                            Environment.NewLine + "Hit Ok and try again.")
        Else
            'do something

        End If
    End Sub
```

What I want to do is have a class that can handle the events of all my forms so I can reuse this code.  Ideally, I would like it structured in a way that I would not have to write code directly in any of my forms.

```
Handles Form1.btnSubmit, Form2.btnEnter
```

Is this possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to write a public class having static validation methods and call these methods in your user-interface.

```
public class MyValidation
   public Shared Function IsEmpty(ByVal data as String) as Boolean
      if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) Then
         return true
      End If
      return false
   End Function
End Class
```